# Index matrix from a txt file

Tags: python, matrix

I read a matrix from a txt file but I can not call for a specific element on it

matrix:

```
['5x5\n', 
 '0.49832186379667975\t0.08107739538827341\t0.34862619622310764\t0.6371236836985522\t0.38901192241601756\t\n'...
```

code :

```
f = open('matrix.txt','r+')
lines=f.readlines()
print(lines[1][2])
>>>4
```

but it should be 0.34862619622310764
How can I index it?

Comment: `print(lines[1][2])` is just giving you the second line and THEN giving you the 2nd index in that same line (which is a string now) which would be '4' in that string, what you want to do is select the second line as you've done `lines = lines[1]` and then `split()` the string and then select the 2nd index from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing the string, not the list. What you see is `'4'`, not `4`. (For clarity, don't use `print(x)`, or use `print(repr(x))`.)

What you forgot is to `.split('\t')` each line.

The typical way to do it is:

```
with open('matrix.txt') as f:
  lines = [line.split('\t') for line in f]
# Here the file auto-closes
```

If you want to turn the strings into actual *numbers*, don't forget to parse them along the way:

```
number_lines = [[float(s) for s in line.split('\t') if s] for line in f]
```

The `if s` part is required because your lines contain a trailing `'\t'`, so the list after the spit will contain an `''` which cannot be converted to a number. An empty string is falsy so it will be filtered out.

It will fail on the first line, though; so you'll have to handle it differently:

```
with open('matrix.txt') as f:
  first_line = f.readline()
```

Comment: I still can not reach the element I want. I am using python 3.6

Comment: Print `lines`; it is a _linear_ list of numbers. You have to construct the 5x5 matrix yourself; parse the first line (`map(int, first_line.split('x'))` should work), get the dimensions, follow on with the assignment.

Comment: I have to use standard libraries, is there any solition without any outher lib?

Comment: Hint: `[100,200,300,400,500,600,700][2:5] == [300, 400, 500]`, and you totally can replace `2` and `5` with variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just go like this:

```
f = open('matrix.txt','r+')
lines=f.readlines()
print(lines[1].split('\t')[2])
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'